# Id transistor code Smd: N3L1

Tags: identification

Could you help me identify a smd transistor that has the following code: N3L1 (Sot23)
thanks for your help
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It likely is a [Si2303CDS](https://www.vishay.com/docs/69991/si2303cd.pdf) made by Vishay.
It would explain (the vias in) the polygons at the drain and source.
If lucky (depending on other board components) you might be able to measure the drain source diode with a diode test.

Comment: Hello Huisman, thank you for your prompt response.
How do you know what a Si2303CDS is? Could you teach me?
Actually I looked for the Si2303CDS datasheet and it appears: Si2303CDS (N3) *
* Marking Code.
I also commented that between source and drain mark 65 ohms, clearly has damage in these terminals.
This transistor is used on a Ricoh multifunction printer board, model MP305 + and its function is to deliver + 5V to the paper input sensor.
I could not get the replacement, but I'll keep looking ...

Comment: I searched the internet for "ic marking N3" and found some IC's. I read the datasheets of the IC's and check what component it is and if the marking is correct. Sometimes board layout give hints, like here.